# Integrate Sitecore with External Workflow engine

Tags: workflow, sitecore, k2, skelta

Is it possible to integrate Sitecore with external workflow engine (K2, Skelta), and if so, how to connect external workflow with Sitecore content item,  and do i need to implement new interface in Sitecore (like workbox).

The reason why i need this, because current Sitecore workflow does not have all features that other workflow engines have, like escalating workflow items or parallel approval steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways. The most common way is to use Sitecore workflow actions to hand items off to the external workflow system. Another way is to implement the IWorkflowProvider and possibly related interfaces to abstract the external workflow engine completely. I personally have never tried either approach, so I can't provide any detail.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try both ways, and i will post the result here as soon as i finish

Answer (score 1):

According to the sitecore website they list open architecture as a benefit. They even go so far as to say.

"Integrate with third-party systems: Sitecore CMS provides a full data integration and
abstraction layer that allows you to connect to any database, web service or other external systems"

So theoretically it is possible. (Full disclosure, I do work for K2) I will ask around to see if anyone internally has done this before.

Anyone else out there done anything similar?